# 120v DC to 5v DC conversion

Tags: dc-dc-converter

For our e-Kart project we need to power a raspberry pi 3 (5V 2A) of a battery of 120V.

We are having trouble finding a good solution as these high voltages seem to high for a conventional (self made) SMPS and its not AC voltage that needs conversion.

Someone suggested using a normal USB wall charger directly. Would this be a possibility? And if not, why?

Any suggestions are welcome, as of now it seems that an extra battery might be needed..

Kind regards!

EDIT:

We were able to produce 5V using a Sony wall charger!

However, as Transistor noted below, it seems that this wont work with all charger types, the one that shipped with the Raspberry Pi (notably bigger than the Sony one) did not work.

The Sony one was rated 100-240VAC as was the RPi one.

Comment: 120V DC battery?

Comment: Have you tried webench.ti.com they seem to have a have designs that meet what you are looking for.

Comment: What current is being drawn from the 120 V battery? If it is significantly more, say tenfold, than the current the RPi circuitry needs, then perhaps you could tap off a few intermediate cells to get a potential difference somewhat closer to 5 V.

Comment: The term "e-Kart" makes me think of something like a go-cart, so I suspect having wires from a USB wall charger would be a bit limiting on the range of motion of the e-kart. Unless you mean e-kart in the sense of a web shopping basket, in which case a 120 V battery makes no sense.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The suggested USB charger is meant to be connected to the batteries (which might work!), not to a wall socket ;)

Comment: @marcelm OK, I give up: what is an "e-Kart"? Google tells me nothing.

Comment: I have cheap Chinese chargers here that start at 76VDC~84VDC and get a decent >68% efficiency at 85VDC all. Don't ask why I know this. It may be worth a shot to just try some at lowest battery voltage minus 5V and keep an eye if they get too hot and/or keep working for a few hours. unless it's a production design, those need to be better.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Think go-kart; it's a [small race vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kart_racing). That also explains the relatively high voltage battery, you need power to get going quickly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Someone suggested using a normal USB wall charger directly. Would this be a possibility?

It is a possibility but a little unlikely.

[image]

*Figure 1. SMPS diagram.*

Most SMPS use the configuration shown in Figure 1. At first glance it would appear that since the PSU has a rectifier anyway that you should be able to connect DC either before or after the rectifier. The problem is the DC voltage: even a "universal" 100 - 240 V AC PSU running at lowest input voltage of 100 V AC will have a peak of 100√2 = 140 V on the DC bus. Your 120 V battery might be just too low to work.

If you can find one that will work down to 85 V AC (-> 120 V peak) you might get by. Some laptop chargers will do this and you could consider this as a first stage voltage reduction into, say, a 19 V to 5 V converter of your own design.

As suggested in the comments, you could design your own. 120 V DC is in the dangerous category, however, so a pre-fabbed solution would probably be better.

Comment: I've definitely seen universal PSUs with a range of 90-250V, and 90√2 = 127V. Still a little higher, but I'd say it's definitely worth getting a bucket of USB chargers at a thrift store ;)

Comment: Am I correct in remembering that modern "wall-wart" supplies utilise an extra winding on ~some~ transformer to **bootstrap** the full functionality (with improved no-load efficiency or something as the target), and so an AC supply is a necessity? Whereas an old SMPS might rectify the input to power the switching circuitry, so a DC input would still result in successful operation. Your block diagram doesn't show where the power for the HF switch comes from.

Comment: You could be right, but I thought that was only on 115/230 switched types. There was an answer in the past few days with a schematic. I'll have a quick look.

Comment: I don't think youll find a SMPS running mains 50/60 Hz on the transformer the inductance is too low, maybe though